# Reading JSON file into a QJsonDocument

Tags: qt, qt5

This is the structure of my json:

```
{
    "images": [
        {
            "imagename": "banner.jpg",
            "shapes": [
            ]
        },
        {
            "imagename": "banner.png",
            "shapes": [
            ]
        },
        {
            "imagename": "logo.png",
            "shapes": [
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is the code I have:

```
QString filename = jsonFilePath;

QString val;
QFile file;
file.setFileName(filename);
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);
val = file.readAll();
file.close();
QJsonDocument d = QJsonDocument::fromJson(val.toUtf8());
qDebug() << d;
```

When I run the above code, and try and output `d` using `qDebug()` all that is printed to the console is `QJsonDocument()`.

Comment: what is the output of `qDebug() << val;` and `qDebug() << file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);`

Comment: @eyllanesc `""` and `true`

Comment: change to `file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);`

Comment: @eyllanesc unfortunately that didn't work

Comment: val should be a QByteArray, not a QString, to void unnecessary conversions. Probably not the problem here though, as there’s no non-ascii in your example JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works OK if there are no runtime errors. I'd suggest to check for runtime errors:

1. Check the return result of `file.open()`.
2. Use a second argument of `QJsonDocument::fromJson()` to catch JSON parsing errors and print them like that:

```
    QJsonParseError err;
    QJsonDocument d = QJsonDocument::fromJson(val.toUtf8(), &err);
    qDebug() << d << err.errorString();
```

Hope this helps to catch the error.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the toJson() method when printing a QJsonDocument

```
qDebug() << "Json Document:" << d.toJson();
```